# ExtJS grid with pagination, instead of combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, grid, multi-select

I am creating a list of items, that are in combobox, but I am asked to create it with grid and to include pagination. Is it possible to create a grid with list of items, and then select them like in dropdown menu (with multiselect feature) and when clicked a submit button get the values and process it through php file.?

My thoughts: Grid is for displaying list of information, and the text in grid can be link text. But as far as I know you can't select item from grid then process by clicking submit buttons.

Anyways, whats the best way of doing it? And if its not possible with neither one of the methods, can I use multiselect to make the list? With displayfield and valuefield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can add checkbox to each item in grid and then do some action to selected items.

```
Ext.define('Your.items.Grid' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    title : 'Grid with checkboxes',
    store: 'Items',
    // This line adds checkboxes
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'), 

    columns: [
         // Some columns here
    ],    
    initComponent: function() {

        this.dockedItems = [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [{
                itemId: 'process',
                text: 'Process',
                action: 'process' // Bind to some action and then process
            }]
        },
        { // Here is pagination
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            dock:'top',
            store: 'Items',
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying items {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No items to display"
        }];            
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Hope I understood your question correctly

Comment: thanks for the reply I am sure its useful, but I am not too advanced with extjs, and it must be done with lists